# Is there a way to send gulp.src(some data) instead of a glob?

Tags: json, node.js, gulp, glob, node-streams

I want to be able to edit JSON then send it through the gulp stream. I know there's gulp-json-edit but I want to understand how it's done and do it myself. In this case, to change the Basic authorization.

For example, something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./core-config.json'));


data.local.ENDPOINT.CORE.BASIC = "Basic Stuff";

gulp.src(data)
    .pipe(somestuff)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

However, this of course doesn't work because `data` isn't a glob. How can I then manipulate `data` in a way that I can then pass it to gulp.src()?

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I wrote a module that can turn a regular object stream into a vinyl stream: [`vinylize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinylize). It's mostly useful for static site generation, but If I understand your question correctly it should be able to handle your use case as well.

Your example code using `vinylize()` would look like this:

```
var vinylize = require('vinylize');

var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./core-config.json'));
data.local.ENDPOINT.CORE.BASIC = "Basic Stuff";

vinylize([data], {
  path: 'core-config.json',
  contents: JSON.stringify(data),
  ignoreSourceProps: true,
})
.pipe(somestuff)
.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely looks like it'd work, but I was more looking for how to actually do that conversion your plugin does and why it's what gulp.src needs. I'll look into the plugin sourcecode, but node is (so far) all very confusing to me!